# ranges-v3 flattern with move

Tags: c++, range-v3

I am trying to do a flatten on  a container of container into one dimension, with views::join and views::move, but I have hard time to understand the difference between move first and then join VS join and then move. Try2 worked as expected, but can someone help me to understand what happening under the hood that so that  the Try1 ends up copying ? somewhere the move did not work. Thanks !

wandbox link to the code: https://wandbox.org/permlink/BeFI3wjBiUPbsMA2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

int main()
{     
    auto words = std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>{
        {"Hello", "World"},
        {"ni","hao"}
    };
    // Try1
    auto result1 = words
        | ranges::views::move
        | ranges::views::join
        | ranges::to<std::vector<std::string>>();

    std::cout<<ranges::views::all(ranges::views::join(words))<<std::endl;
    //[Hello,World,ni,hao]

    // Try2   
    auto result2 = words
        | ranges::views::join
        | ranges::views::move
        | ranges::to<std::vector<std::string>>();

    std::cout<<ranges::views::all(ranges::views::join(words))<<std::endl;
    //[,,,]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`move` means that the moved from object is in a valid but unspecified state. It *does not* mean that the moved from object will be cleared out. So both outputs are perfectly valid.

My guess is that the first `move` doesn't erase the original strings because of small-string-optimization, where that might be the more efficient thing to do.

In fact, if the first `move` actually moved from `words`, then `result2` would have all  empty strings. Again, this would be completely valid.

Comment: But being under SSO is property of input string, isn't it? I don't see how would be explain question about inconsistency that `join | move` leaves string empty, but `move | join` over the very same string does not. Being under SSO should be transferred in both tries.

Comment: No, that's not *required*. The implementation may choose to move in some cases, but not others.

Answer (score 0):

This is "how to fix" answer, without explanation "why" part. I don't know how this behaviour is documented, not specified in upcoming C++20.

In your example it is enough to add second `ranges::views::move` between `join` and `to` operations.

```
auto result1 = words
    | ranges::views::move
    | ranges::views::join
    | ranges::views::move
    | ranges::to<std::vector<std::string>>();

std::cout<<ranges::views::all(ranges::views::join(words))<<std::endl;
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/ONU5sn4pQrMGWvnD